# Ajax call via JSON returning variables that aren't there and I can't delete or change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a script making an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: pageURL,
    data: loadData,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { //if the call was successful
        console.log(successFunc);
        dataNew = data;
        delete dataNew.total;
        console.log(dataNew);
        console.log(dataNew.total);
        successFunc(dataNew);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) { //throw errors if we fail
        $('#loading').css('display', 'none'); //hide loading popup
        $("#login").modal('hide');

        if (typeof errorFunc !== "undefined") errorFunc();  //if there is a function associated with failing call it

        scripts.throwNetworkError(xhr, status, errorThrown, errorType);
    },
    timeout: 15000    // wait 15 seconds before failing
});
```

It calls to a PHP page that returns a JSON encoded object:

```
$returnData = json_encode($retData);

echo $returnData;
```

The problem is, I was having trouble with a particular variable, $retData->total, that was treating numbers like strings and adding them together like "543" instead of 12.  But no matter what I did, I couldn't fix it.

So I removed every mention to the variable "total" in the PHP script.  Changed the name to "totalNum".  So in the JSON object, totalNum would come through, but ALSO "total", even though that variable doesn't exist!

Below is the result of the console.log(dataNew) that was returned:

```
Object
cart: [Object, Object] (2)
mark0: "XXA"
message: "delete"
name: null
out_of_stock: null
part_num: "854210"
quantity: null
total: "0196.443.08"
totalNum: 199.52
vendor: null
```

You can see "total" is still there.

Also, before I called:

```
console.log(dataNew);
```

I tried:

```
delete dataNew.total;
```

But it's still there.

I can't get rid of this variable from either end.

How do I get rid of it?  Keeping in mind, ideally, I want the nice numeric variable "totalNum" to be "total", but "total" in its current form won't be altered, edited, or deleted no matter what I try.

Comment: We'd have to see the PHP used to create the array you encode.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Wouldn't let me.  Said it was too long.

Comment: Can you copy the relevant code here?

Comment: Please, go check XHR response in browser's devtools: if `total` in raw JSON there — it is PHP to blame, if `total` is not in raw JSON — it is JS to blame. Note the 'minimal' part https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `
$totalNum = 0;
   $spliceIndex = -1;
   for($i=0;$i<count($partArray);$i++) {
    if($partArray[$i]["part_num"] == $data->part_num) {
     $spliceIndex = $i;     
    } else {
     $totalNum += floatval($partArray[$i]["sub_total"]); 
    }
   }
   array_splice($partArray, $spliceIndex, 1);
   
   $retData->part_num = $data->part_num;   
   $retData->message = "delete";
   $retData->totalNum = $totalNum;
   $retData->cart = $partArray;
      $returnData = json_encode($retData);
 
 echo $returnData;`

Comment: @НЛО Looks like JS is to blame.  But I'm no closer to solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) like [`ajaxSuccess`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) modifying your `request.responseText`.

Comment: Pointed me to where the problem most likely is.  Haven't fixed it yet, but now have a probably lead.  Thank you.

Comment: Great!  Fixed it.  Thank you!